# K-Way Partitioning QuickSort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quick-sort

I have implemented the K-Way Partitioning algorithm which is based on the [Peter Taylor's solution](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89663/an-algorithm-for-k-way-array-partitioning).

Which works but i want fill the `q` array which is the borders of each pivot. also note that the array of pivots is already given and i need to implement it without the use of std functions.

i think it should be similar to `sorted` in python(`sorted(l,key=lambda x:[x[y]for y in k]`) that's not change the pivots and doing it in-place.

The equivalent key function to the python version would be:

```
[](T* a, T* b) {
    for (auto i : pivots) if (a[i] != b[i]) return a[i] < b[i];
    return false;
}
```

please have a look at my [test cases](https://tio.run/##rRjbbtpI9Bl/xWmqRbYxTWzIS4yReKmEWq0qLbv7wPLgGJcMNsY3klYR/fXsOTO@2zRu1Eg1M@c25z5n6oTheOc4L@9Z4PinrQszdkzS2LUPc6mEOXaSuHFaBaXs4H54mEvSKWHBDgL74Cah7biQpFtTkt6Hsb072HAMHFeSHB8FwPJZCmP2aKfunTRgQQqPtn9ykTg83fvMQWCS2ilzgHDO8RSkblzFLmXnGCQpLIfAFJP2mRCxoe8P/iMN7o9HH46hG9vpMZ6XfDHbPaQK8L3ZIJv1I5tbPcX1pLN60r27TIeQQlqTqBu9PaJT3ZIkx2cIuZAtArVz038oViX8jChpeXdXi8mzNEgfWDKe88CCBexDFuKzoM3j1SLE34JIeeaLH2IlcSfg/pVoosjYTU9xALIQOhdooYFC0luiZj1FzV4XdSkr2mpZPfTqK2zWQ5jVV5jVQ9i7vsLedQhDnqpeLUmtrKhIMMsDVCL6mcRacl@QekFeKaxRCVLFQoFRitSWKK2RtVklJUtFAWR4qTXH1D2EPvZE7LK8S67mWbv89K/9/YsdpyxlxwAqvRPw7/HItpA82aG8UsHWAL/3aCusgOShlapt4j9a3OPiHheEMOHM2UnjMJdNIhYah/nHJ7F4QCdxqX6o4V6FSOGMz/zLRXwFebFGhg2W2mJNDBulRNMf128oiDQY5kRmQXQupeGZe1QSSWEEullD7BBBrDAGXQOvi2wFZHR@VBTxDT@upHl6YJgWskdls1Ogrqswx9tgsYdNXNUWT1iyr5qR/@1HozrwXNu5fuKW52AjiKKukzI1F@sdeRZNGQ7R5hmq3Kalv9143Fbl/JoBuy4DOkW95pm@3un0UFvX@s6rMpSofVXRXZWmlXM1XXIsz4y2H1SfsmhfArL63QkIlnpReyygiQir569jnMorzDaUt4K46qEVeKyeyXvrpgR8xS7Dr0Rm6SabxSYbjZoO9hjPZLapu41KhVE51MFZ6uwpuW4ob8h8TCKPdQUOkSN9w@XvNx3Z3EyGemQK7qqNZ6n8cjd9KjtY1mbwG7LHY5pQXwE1Ev0mFD@x@EmybVJzJyUi3o2tJBRB6uwqyJGEs7oYEYtq9BZa3NmUeME2GVM4oF0WhCM5HofKtWG2CNj2GxEU/RWtRoPQtqGwfI0SNlrUqJHSVZxB@CjSyBUoj1pfrNHRuOrHSWwj6pgxEONI15K2nedivuYxY3F6sn0Ru5@EDsSd0BU7r@rrC5ohS4zqwI12o@SldTZfuHNtFsj81qZdgH6cYMnwDTV@fUIz6RLUBW4C9wmW62BDM26uWgH2NoIN1cxguFkbKsGlQe1ynS3nKnx9CjO6Jk48KZLYDrYyPXvkP//@/FmhsVkalDWMzDcm/szAABU8XGI1S4NBFnJGpTJFDMOYGCQQXzgpzGZwtQzwJHT6Io7t73dXBHODLQ7EndIDIZk8NFgIsVwzBf4AmQ7wSLNCOiehUzS4Qvh5gCejqeN5V2QoojcaBGO6ZpV8@heHV7TZC232qA3auc@1KS4uxu8KYTe2X0QNGPXowUC8I0GO1uQk7E04dPK3XI0ZgX24KblLCeeqS/8LPrLgTS695Leq9Ei8XJNXBXsdgq@@kGnAWcvcECdFM2AoFTdoolqCLQ6GHE59tzwYVTu/tKdIUcPuN@fBDnboWVgN@aA4hHtQJCrRFTiyrZhgWzgi3lsOn2UvjqMf2aPbmEiL1lH2@y@NoXIlbNSLldHRM4YQ6fnCyBeTfDGtNpTabco02GOianDQwDc7aKgLl/B9fevVtz4V0qhyoR6aAGlwrVaa4tZObUhOzgOO93aK2AGHZFHVwY5x2guoONH961CLdCWnyRO8SYRuiAylIckALG@8xLs5DC2atOQaTaqJhm7MqeYXiKbYkuONNFCvpfrMLHszX2mOy8VMyNXqmE0pQtljZMG7cXv@QAFW9/DBB5euyUcgedvjD5r2sV0jZufc6fUa14WdRcSUC08DMfv2fRj86vFF9PlMV/rd6FDnLWYZr5nlj/Uuw/yfz4higLq@rtpgvDVRMi260ATnBIcLBAdB0J0xfter53DZsnIV6TSHl3SRUX8@RBN6q1b2U9wfGp2KRh/pWpXwSusev/gTP8ZWKf57Azt43lPrgLe2VjVvp7pFvAb/Tvh3apGYWys2BZloB2xCT2g2VTJmSidUcM0m9YagZkaq2WsoC3JGauaInDXDGA2MUWD0BqYaUwFmOk/@bGNUN5Nyc85@81IoFLCayv8W3esa/qpS1dJvONloO/lXzKyw97Vv2sBM2/ZNeeH0Mel3nc9Xtw3MbVuz21KztppinWkc6RbDsokMi2HRRBOL0d2I9WKxWz4RZPREfi39Dw) because I'm not entirely sure if changing the pivots is OK here in Peter Taylor's solution.

It needs to satisfy this properties at the end:

```
    A[p .. r]
    pivots[0 .. (k-1)]  an array of k ordered values (in ascending order)
    q[0 .. (2k-1)]      output array of borders
    At the end:
        A[p .. q[0]-1] < pivots[0]
        A[q[0] .. q[1]-] = pivots[0]
        pivots[0] < A[q[1] .. q[2]-1] < pivots[1]
        A[q[2] .. q[3]-1] = pivots[1]
        ...
        pivots[i-1] < A[q[2i-1] .. q[2i]-1] < pivots[i] 0 < i < k-1
        A[q[2i] .. q[2i+1]-1] = pivots[i]       0 < i < k-1
        ...
        pivots[k-2] < A[q[2k-3] .. q[2k-2]-1] < pivots[k-1]
        A[q[2k-2] .. q[2k-1]-1] = pivots[k-1]
        A[q[2k-1] .. r] > pivots[k-1]
```

```
#pragma once
template <class T>
class KWayPartition {
private:
    void swap(T* a, T* b) { T temp = *a; *a = *b; *b = temp; }
    int partition(T* A, int low, int high, T* lp,int* q)
    {
        if (A[low] > A[high]){
            swap(&A[low], &A[high]);
        }
        int j = low + 1;
        int g = high - 1, k = low + 1;
        T p = A[low], qq = A[high];
        while (k <= g) {
            if (A[k] < p) {
                swap(&A[k], &A[j]);
                j++;
            }
            else if (A[k] >= qq) {
                while (A[g] > qq && k < g){
                    g--;
                }
                swap(&A[k], &A[g]);
                g--;
                if (A[k] < p) {
                    swap(&A[k], &A[j]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            k++;
        }
        j--;
        g++;
        swap(&A[low], &A[j]);
        swap(&A[high], &A[g]);
        *lp = j;
        return g;
    }

    void insertionSort(T A[], T r) {
        T ki;
        int j=0;
        for (int i=1;i<r;i++) {
            ki = A[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && A[j] > ki) {
                A[j+1] = A[j];
                j--;
            }
            A[j+1] = ki;
        }
    }
    void KPartition (T* A, T* pivots,int *q, int p, int r, int sp, int sr) {
        if (r<=p) {
            return;
        }
        if (sp<sr) {
            insertionSort(A,r);
        }
        else {
            int mid = p+(r-p)/2;
            int idx = partition(A, p, r, &pivots[mid],q);
            KPartition(A, pivots,q,p, idx - 1,r,mid - 1);
            KPartition(A, pivots,q,idx + 1, r ,mid+1,sr);
        }
    }
public:
    virtual void Partition (T* A, T* pivots, int* q, int p, int r, int k) {
        KPartition(A, pivots,q, p,r+1, 0,0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

## Give variables meaningful names

While short variable names sometimes make sense, it's really hard to make sense of your code when it's mostly one and two letter variables. If you do stick with very short variable names for some reason, make sure you explain them in comments, and/or if you want to use the same names as in some paper or online article, use exactly the same names and add a reference to that paper or article.

## Use the standard library

There is lots of functionality in the [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) that you should use instead of reinventing the wheel. For example:

- Instead of implementing your own `swap()`, just use [`std::swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).
- Use [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead of `insertionSort()`.
- Use [`std::partition()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) instead of writing your own.
- Use [`std::midpoint()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint) if you can use C++20.

## This should not be a `class`

In C++ it is perfectly fine to have functions that live outside of a `class`. A `class` without any member variables is not very useful. So write a free function `KWayPartition()`. Any helper functions can be put into an [anonymous namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces) so they don't pollute the global namespace.

I also don't see why you have a `virtual` function `Partition()`, which in turn just calls the non-`virtual` `KPartition()`. Making a class virtual has a performance impact, so doing it for no good reason is bad.

## Use `std::size_t` for indices

Using `int` for indices is problematic on 64-bit platforms where an array can have more elements than you can represent using an `int`. Use [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) for sizes, counts and indices where possible, as that type is guaranteed to be large enough for anything that can be stored in memory.

## Consider passing iterators

Instead of passing a pointer to an array and one or more indices, consider passing [iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) instead. As a bonus, this would allow your \$k\$-way partitioning algorithm to work on some containers other than regular arrays. Since you already made your code a template, it shouldn't be very hard; just make `T` the iterator type. Although you might also want to consider the possibility of the set of elements you want to partition and the set of pivots to be stored in different container types; in that case you want to have multiple template parameters.

Even better would be to pass [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges), if you can use C++20.

## Example rewrite

Here is how it can look instead with iterators and use of the standard library. It also outputs the "borders".

```
template<typename ArrayIt, typename PivotsIt, typename BordersIt>
void KWayPartition(ArrayIt array_begin, ArrayIt array_end,
                   PivotsIt pivots_begin, PivotsIt pivots_end,
                   BordersIt borders_begin, BordersIt borders_end)
{
    if (array_begin == array_end) {
        return;
    }

    if (pivots_begin == pivots_end) {
        std::sort(array_begin, array_end);
    } else {
        auto pivots_mid = pivots_begin;
        std::advance(pivots_mid, std::distance(pivots_begin, pivots_end) / 2);
        auto array_mid = std::partition(array_begin, array_end, [&](auto& item){
            return item < *pivots_mid;
        });

        auto borders_mid = borders_begin;
        std::advance(borders_mid, std::distance(borders_begin, borders_end) / 2);
        *borders_mid = array_mid;

        KWayPartition(array_begin, array_mid, pivots_begin, pivots_mid, borders_begin, borders_mid);
        KWayPartition(++array_mid, array_end, ++pivots_mid, pivots_end, ++borders_mid, borders_end);
    }
}
```

The way to use it is like so:

```
std::vector<int> data = …;
std::vector<int> pivots = …;
std::vector<decltype(data)::iterator> borders(pivots.size());
KWayPartition(data.begin(), data.end(), pivots.begin(), pivots.end(), borders.begin(), borders.end());
```

And the vector `borders` will contain iterators into `data` where the borders of the partitions are, in the same way `std::partition()` returns a single iterator. Changing this into an array of pairs of iterators describing the start and end of each partition is left as an excercise for the reader. The above code also doesn't handle all corner cases properly, for example `borders` might not be filled in correctly if some of the partitions are empty.

Comment: @g-sliepen You probably meant array_begin in the sort, and it gives this error: ‘void pivots_mid’ has incomplete type.

Comment: I fixed my example code so it compiles (at least with a C++14-compliant compiler). It's a bit unfortunate that there are still so many assignments where "you can't use standard stuff". I think it would be better if they first had you implement your own sort once, prove that it is correct and does the same as `std::sort`, and then when the next assignment comes you are just allowed to use `std::sort` and not have to reinvent the wheel again. That you need to use a `class` with a `virtual` function with no explanation why is also not very educative.

Comment: Thanks again now it works, how should i fill the elements of `q` from `borders` should i use the `std::copy` function.

Comment: If `q` is a regular array then you can pass `std::begin(q)` and `std::end(q)` as values for the `borders_begin` and `borders_end` parameters. Or if you only have a pointer `q` and the number of elements `r`, you can pass `q` and `q + r`.

Comment: @YaserJafariJ: Code Review is not a homework solving service; we just *review* the code *you* wrote. If you have a *specific* question about how to do something in C++, search on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) if there is already an answer for that, or if not ask a question there.